# Correlation in simple line regression model

Tags: regression, self-study, correlation

I am reading a book on Statistics and come across the following.

Assume a simple Gauss-Markov model on sample data $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)$, i.e.
$y_i = a + b x_i + \epsilon_i$, where $\epsilon_i$ are normal random noise.

$\bar{y} \equiv \frac{\sum^n_{i=1}y_i}{n}$

$\hat{y}_i = \hat{a} + \hat{b}x_i$, where $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ are regression coefficients.

Define the correlation by method-of-moments estimate, we have

$r^2 \equiv \frac{\{\sum^n_{i=1} (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})\}^2}{\sum^n_{i=1} (x_i-\bar{x})^2\sum^n_{i=1} (y_i-\bar{y})^2}$
$=\hat{b}^2\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar{x})^2}{\sum^n_{i=1}(y_i-\bar{y})^2}$
$=\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}(\hat{y}_i-\bar{y})^2}{\sum^n_{i=1}(y_i-\bar{y})^2}$

So far so good, but there is a small problem in the numerator of the final step. In the numerator,

$\hat{b}^2 \sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\bar{x})^2=\sum^n_{i=1}(\hat{b}x_i-\hat{b}\bar{x})^2=\sum^n_{i=1}(\hat{a}+\hat{b}x_i-(\hat{a}+\hat{b}\bar{x}))^2$

In the final step, $(\hat{a}+\hat{b}x_i)$ is of course equal to $\hat{y}_i$ but the second term $(\hat{a}+\hat{b}\bar{x})$ is not $\bar{y}$. So I can't get the same result in the book.

Any help please?